# React Fragments shorthand <></> breaks VSCode syntax highlighting

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

This code will not throw any errors or warnings, but the syntax highlighting is off. I have tried different themes but they all have this problem. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What is exactly off about the syntax highlight? Are you expecting both <> and </> to be highlighted? I currently see a vertical line that points to its partner whenever my cursor is over the brackets.

Comment: @SILENT I think OP means on how `export default ExampleComponent;` and brackets are all in turquoise color, instead of their usual colors

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? Do you see this when you disable your extensions? Use `Developer: reload with extensions disabled` to check this

Comment: @MattBierner Your comment helped me find the problem. Disabling https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring displayed the fragments properly, thanks!

Comment: Are you running the `dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring` (Babel ES6/ES7
) extension? If so, I believe you might want to get rid of it (superfluous, outdated anyway).

Answer (score 5):

Like Johannes suggested, try removing `dzannotti.vscode-babel-coloring` in your extension. It is an outdated extension that does not support JSX fragment syntax.